# Asynchronous test function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, testing

I'm trying to create a function to testing asynchronous code, but I'm kind of lost, I want the TEST_F and TEST function below also work with asynchronous code, such as loading the image for example.

```
const CHECK = (actual, expected) => {
    return (actual === expected);
};

const TEST = (name, ...testFunctions) => {
    console.log(name+':');
    for (let test of testFunctions)
        console.log(test);
};

const TEST_F = (name, f) => {
    const tStart = performance.now();

    const check = f();

    const tEnd = performance.now();
    const duration = tEnd - tStart;

    const details = name + ': ' + '(' + duration + ') = ' + check;

    return details;
};

const imageDownload = (path, successCallback) => {
    let img = new Image();

    img.addEventListener("load", successCallback, false);

    img.src = path;

    return img;
};

TEST("TestImage", 
    TEST_F("testImageDownload", () => {
        let spyCountSuccess = 0;
        const expectedCountSuccess = spyCountSuccess + 1;

        const successCallback = () => {
            spyCountSuccess++;
        };
        const pathImage = 'https://i.imgur.com/Wutekcp.jpg';
        imageDownload(pathImage, successCallback);

        const actualCountSuccess = spyCountSuccess;

        return CHECK(actualCountSuccess, expectedCountSuccess);
    })

);
```

With the code above I will always i get false, even if the image is loaded, because I am not dealing right with the concept of asynchronous, I would like to understand how to adapt the code thus to also test ascincrono code.

Comment: Have you considered using an existing test framework that handles async code such as mocha?

Comment: @Paul I'm just studying. I like to create my tools, I learn more like this. I want to add the asynchronous code tests in my test tool that I created to learn more about testing. https://github.com/perdugames/cacau

Answer (score 0):

I was able to test the asynchronous code after some tests. I do not know if I'll keep it that way, but it's working, I'll try to study these lines and see what I can improve:

```js
const CHECK = (actual, expected) => {
    return (actual === expected);
};

const TEST = (name, ...testFunctions) => {
    console.log(name+':');
    for (let test of testFunctions)
        if(test === undefined)
            continue;
        else
            console.log(test);
};

const TEST_F = (name, f) => {
    const tStart = performance.now();
    const check = f();
    const tEnd = performance.now();
    const duration = tEnd - tStart;
    
    const details = name + ': ' + '(' + duration + ') = ' + check;
  
    return details;
};

const TEST_F_ASYNC = (name, f) => {
    const tStart = performance.now();
    f((check) => {
      const tEnd = performance.now();
      const duration = tEnd - tStart;
      
      const details = name + ': ' + '(' + duration + ') = ' + check;
    
      console.log(details);
    });
    
};

const imageDownload = (path, successCallback) => {
    let img = new Image();
    
    img.addEventListener("load", successCallback, false);
    
    img.src = path;
    
    return img;
};

TEST("TestImage", 
    TEST_F_ASYNC("testAsync", (done) => {
        let spyCountSuccess = 0;
        const expectedCountSuccess = spyCountSuccess + 1;
        
        const successCallback = () => {
            spyCountSuccess++;
            const actualCountSuccess = spyCountSuccess;
            const result = CHECK(actualCountSuccess, expectedCountSuccess)
            done(result);
        };
        const pathImage = 'https://i.imgur.com/Wutekcp.jpg';
        imageDownload(pathImage, successCallback);
        
    }),
    
    TEST_F('testSync', () => {
        return CHECK(1, 1);
    })

);
```